# Is it possible to stop a parallel process in CUDA

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cuda, gpu

I am learning C++ CUDA, and I need to use GPUs to search for something in a very big array in Device memory. Is it possible to `stop` the process once a kernel finds what we are looking for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to interrupt or cancel a CUDA kernel from host code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34989481/how-to-interrupt-or-cancel-a-cuda-kernel-from-host-code) (though note that there are probably more efficient ways than the ones provided in the answer regarding your computation)